# I'm trying to get all the links from a certain container, but i get an output on "None" for each 'href' in the html

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get a lists of links from this webpage but i can't figure it out why i keep having an output on None!

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
import os
import re
import pandas as pd



brand = Request('https://www.quattroruote.it/listino/ricerca-per-marca.html',headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(brand).read()
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'lxml')
links = []
for a in bsObj:
    contBrand = bsObj.findAll('dd',attrs={'class':'brand'})
    for link in contBrand:
        link.find('a')
        links.append(link.get('href'))
    print(links)
```

the output of this process is this:

```
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 
None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 
None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 
None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 
None, None, None]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 
None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 
None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 
None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 
None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 
None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 
None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 
None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 
None, None, None, None, None]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 
None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 
None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 
None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 
None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 
None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 
None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 
None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 
None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 
None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 
None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 
None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 
None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

While it should give me somenthig like this(this is only the first one):

```
['/listino/abarth']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really suggest you to use [requests module](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). here is the snippet that works fine with urllib. You can compare it with your code and find where you went wrong.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, urljoin, Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

brand = Request('https://www.quattroruote.it/listino/ricerca-per-marca.html',headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(brand).read()
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'lxml')

links = []
contBrand = bsObj.findAll('dd',attrs={'class':'brand'})
for link in contBrand:
    link = link.find('a').get('href')
    #links.append(urljoin('https://www.quattroruote.it', link))
    # use urljoin if you want to get the complete url
    links.append(link)
print(links)
```